# How to show that $ B(y_n , \frac{1}{n}) \cap (\cup _{n=1}^{ \infty} A_n) \neq \emptyset ?$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Prove that every totally bounded  metrics space is separable

**My attempt** :   separable mean countable with  dense subset

Let $(X, d)$  be  a totally bounded metric space . For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ , there exist  a finite  subset of $A_n$ of $ X$  such that $ X=  \cup \{ B( x, 1/n) : x \in A_n \}$  . Let $A= \cup _{n=1}^{ \infty} A_n $is countable union  of finite set implies $A$ is  countable

Now i have to show that  $A$ is dense in $X$

By definition of dense set : For $x \in  X $ and $ r > 0$ , we have  $B(x,r) \cap A \neq  \emptyset $
according to the given above statement  take $r = \frac{1}{n}$ and $x= y_n$ then $ B(y_n , \frac{1}{n}) \cap (\cup _{n=1}^{ \infty} A_n)  \neq \emptyset$

My problem is that  how to show  that $ B(y_n , \frac{1}{n}) \cap (\cup _{n=1}^{ \infty} A_n)  \neq \emptyset ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that $B(x,1/n)\cap A$ is non-empty.

As $X=\bigcup_{z\in A_n} B(z,1/n)$ there is $z\in A_n$ with $x\in B(z,1/n)$.
That is $d(z,x)<1/n$. So also $z\in B(x,1/n)$ and $z\in A$. Therefore
$B(x,1/n)\cap A$ is non-empty.